# show data specific in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this data in mongodb

```
 > use mongo
switched to db mongo
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556c77c334e275d2ce8b2870"), "fname" : "Carlos", "lname" : "Perez", "telf" : 2316789 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556c77e034e275d2ce8b2871"), "fname" : "Juan", "lname" : "Alvarez", "telf" : 2323456 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556c780334e275d2ce8b2872"), "fname" : "Roberto", "lname" : "Sabina", "telf" : 2398753 }
```

this is my get router

```
//Model
mongoose.model('users', {fname: String, lname: String; telf: Number});

//Get Router
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
    console.log(users);
    res.send(users);
   });
});
```

the result in console is good

```
[ { _id: 556c77c334e275d2ce8b2870,
fname: 'Carlos',
lname: 'Perez',
telf: 2316789 },
{ _id: 556c77e034e275d2ce8b2871,
fname: 'Juan',
lname: 'Alvarez',
telf: 2323456 },
{ _id: 556c780334e275d2ce8b2872,
fname: 'Roberto',
lname: 'Sabina',
telf: 2398753 } ]
```

But when I want specific a data, example only (users.fname)

```
//Get Router
    app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
        console.log(users.fname);
        res.send(users);
    });
});
```

in console show me undefined the data, and jade template is empty

```
undefined
```

why is this problem, please help me thanks

Comment: users is array so write users[i].fname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

users is an array. It has items at indexes, it doesn't have keys.
You can access the items with bracket notation, e.g. users[0].

An array also has properties on its prototype which can be called, e.g. users.length. So when you call users.fname it thinks are you trying to access a property on its prototype chain, which doesn't exist so you get undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Properties

You can iterate through the array and log the fname of each item like so..

```
   app.get('/data', function(req, res){
     mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
       users.forEach(function(user) {
         console.log(user.fname);    
       };
       res.send(users);
     });
   });
```

You may also want to just return the fnames from the request to mongo if thats the only data you need...

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html

```
   app.get('/data', function(req, res){
     mongoose.model('users').find({},'fname', function(err, users){
       users.forEach(function(user) {
         console.log(user.fname);    
       };
       res.send(users);
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
    /*
       Here users is an array of objects.
       So, users.fname won't work,
    */

   // This works
   console.log(users[0].fname);

  // or
  for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      console.log(users[i].fname);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution.